# How can I determine what postmount I need for my fork / rotor for front and back

Tags: brakes, shimano, disc-brake, rotor

I am planning to purchase Shimano Saint BL-M820 + BR-M820 hydraulic disc brake set for my Specialized Stumpjumper Comp and I have no idea what post-mount to buy since I changed my fork and I am pretty sure the brakes won't fit with the mount I currently have.

**Specs:**

**Fork:** Fox 36 Float FIT4 factory 27.5+/29" fork - 150mm - tapered - 51mm offset - 15x110mm boost - 2020

**Front brake (current):**  SRAM Guide R, hydraulic disc, organic pads, Guide S4 4-piston caliper, 200mm

**Rear brake (current):** SRAM Guide R, hydraulic disc, organic pads, Guide S4 4-piston caliper, 180mm

Links:

- https://www.specialized.com/mk/en/stumpjumper-comp-alloy-29/p/170575?color=281280-170575
- https://www.bike24.com/p2344376.html?q=saint%20brakes

**Edit:** It is not the postmount but instead the adapter

Thanks

Comment: 74mm post mount is a standard. You won’t find another post mount type for MTB. Unless you mean the adapter  to make the calliper work with different rotor sizes.

Comment: Yes, I think it is actually the adapter.

Comment: If you're not changing rotor sizes, there shouldn't be any reason your existing adapters or lack thereof won't work.